# Replacing an onclick event on a hyperlink with a slightly altered function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, onclick

My problem at the moment is that I have a email hyperlink on a page that opens up a new email pop-up screen. Each time the email link is clicked, the To: field in the email pop up will get populated by the email address attached to the hyperlink. If that email has an apostrophe in it, the first time it is clicked it will work ok, but each time after it will change the apostrophe for '%27' (as seen in picture below).

[image: email link and email pop-up]

The idea in my script here is to put all of the links in the page into an array, search through that array for the one with the class of "EMAILLINK" and replace the onclick event on that link with a function of my own, which removes the '%27' in the link and puts in an apostrophe.

```
<script>
// When the page loads
$(document).ready(function () {

// Load all of the link elements into an array
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Iterate through all of the links on the page
for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {

    // When you find one with a class of "EMAILLINK" (an email link)
    if (allLinks[i].className=="EMAILLINK") {

        // Load the text of the onclick event into a car
        var strOldOnclick = allLinks[i].onclick + '';

        // Create a regex that matches a single quote, along with part of the function
        // used to launch the email pop-up
        var testRegex = /(MailTo\(\'.*\%27.*\',event,.*\))/gi;

        // Check if the link contains an encoded single quote
        if (testRegex.test(strOldOnclick)) {

            // Execute the regex against the onclick event
            // (loads part of it into variable 1 (RegExp.$1))
            testRegex.exec(strOldOnclick);

            // Replace the correct onclick text in your string var

            var newFunc = "alert('NewFunc running'); if(parent&&parent.frames['EWARE_MENU'])fn=parent;"
                + "else fn=opener.parent;"
                + "if(fn&&fn.frames['EWARE_MENU'])"
                + "fn.frames['EWARE_MENU']."
                + RegExp.$1.replace('%27', "\\'") +";"

            // Replace the onclick event for the link with the updated value

            $("Before test: " + [allLinks[i]]).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');

            $([allLinks[i]]).bind("click", Function(newFunc));

        }
    }
}
});
</script>
```

This is the original onclick event on the link when I view the source of the page:

```
if(parent&&parent.frames['EWARE_MENU'])fn=parent;else fn=opener.parent;if(fn&&fn.frames['EWARE_MENU'])fn.frames['EWARE_MENU'].MailTo('R%27Sakai@demo.com',event,'&Key0=3&Key1=116&Key2=169');
```

Note: I know the onclick is getting changed correctly as the alert is coming up when I click on the link, so it is something to do with the way I have changed the Javascript in (var newfunc)

A variation of this works in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome (or Firefox) and that is where it is going to be used.

Comment: With jquery you can just grab the links with the 'EMAILLINK' class there is no need to grab all of the links on the page. What are you asking? What's the issue? Can you clarify

Comment: You can also do that with ordinary Javascript, using `document.getElementByClassName`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `decodeURIComponent` instead of just replacing `%27`?

Comment: @Barmar - put that as an answer, that's all they need to do, other then re-formatting all this code

Comment: @ScottSelby I'm not sure that will address the difference between Chrome/Firefox and IE. He needs to figure out why there are encoded addresses in IE, but not Chrome/FF.

Comment: When I decode that function and then alert it to screen, the apostrophe is not escaped. Will this cause problems when trying to bind the click event?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write a function of your own, just use the JavaScript unescape() function to remove the apostrophe. If MailTo contains the string with the apostrophe:

```
var readableString = unescape(MailTo);
```

Comment: Will this remove the apostrophe altogether? Some emails will need the apos as part of the address

Comment: No, it just replace %27  with an apostrophe. Try it.

Comment: I think I get it now, but the problem is that the only screen I can actually edit or make scripts run on is the one that holds the email hyperlink, I have been trying but after the hyperlink is clicked, I cannot change what is in the comm_to box

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle so I can be of more help.